# Sqlalchemy type for very long text for articles

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

What type should I define in my sqlalchemy definition for text for a article or blog entry? I'm using MySQL.

```
Column('article_text', ???)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Column('article_text', sqlalchemy.UnicodeText())
```

That should work on any supported database, not just mysql.